# Single Click on Apple map leads crashed in my iOS application. What is the possible reason behind it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is only one delegate for it.

```
#pragma mark - Map Delegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"annotation";

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView
                                                                  dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                          initWithAnnotation:annotation
                          reuseIdentifier:reuseId];

    }
    else
    {
            //Update view's annotation reference
            //because we are re-using view that may have
            //been previously used for another annotation...
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spotcrewcellicon_image.png"];
    return annotationView;
}
@end
```

Comment: What is the exception/error message that you receive?  What line does it crash on?  http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Your annotation adopts `MKAnnotation` protocol and implements `-title` method?

Comment: -[VGLResourceImpl length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x125d5ff0

Comment: The exception message indicates that the `length` method (or the `.length` property) was invoked on a class that doesn't support it.  This is possibly caused by treating something as an `NSString` that isn't.  If you set an exception breakpoint as described in the article I linked to, you should be able to find the exact line of code that is causing you a problem.  If you can't figure it out from there, then update your question to include the relevant code

Comment: By "single click on Apple map", do you mean tap on an annotation?  If so, check how you are setting each annotation's `title` and `subtitle` properties.  Make sure they are being set to an `NSString`-type variable.  The exception implies that the title might be getting set to something that is of type VGLResourceImpl instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to perform operations on the annotation for the user's location, a common cause of crashes in viewForAnnotation:

```
if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    return nil;     // Use default system user-location view.
}
```

should solve your problem.